# Implementing user roles and their unique columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am creating an app where I have 3 different types of users. Each user type will have only 2-3 same columns and 4-5 columns which will be unique to that user type.

Example of user types:

```
Admin
Coach
Player
```

My initial approach was to create `User` table with columns `admin, coach, player`. These columns are booleans which define does user have certain role. Admin would have `admin` to `true` and all other columns to false.

This works fine if we all users have same columns like username, password etc. The problem is appearing when we introduce other columns which are unique to some user type. Let's say all Players need to have address. The we have these columns for user table:

```
id
username
password
admin
coach
player
city
address
apartment
zip
etc...
```

For player these columns would be populated, but for Admin and Coach these values would be null.

My second idea was to leave `User` table with values which are common to all user types:

```
id
username
password
admin
coach
player
```

And then create new tables which would be populated only for specific user type:

```
class AdminProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
end

class CoachProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
end

class PlayerProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
end
```

What would be the best practice to model this type of app with multiple user roles and columns which are unique to specific User? Thank you.

Comment: Check [hibenate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-strategies) to get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with second approach of extracting *user* into different table, and then associating each *admin*, *coach* and *player* with them.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

It not only help to keep your code DRY, but also keeps you flexible for modifications in child tables.